# Measure Theory, Homework Monotone Class

Tags: measure-theory

Find a monotone class $\mathcal M$ in $\mathbb R$ which is not a $\sigma$-algebra, even though $\mathbb R \in M$ and $\mathbb R-A \in \mathcal M$ for every $A \in \mathcal M$.

Comment: What did you try? As this is homework you should show some effort

Answer (score 2):

What if you take $\mathcal{M}$ to contain $\varnothing$ and all unbounded intervals of $\Bbb R$? By *interval* I mean any order-convex subset of $\Bbb R$, i.e., any set $I\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that if $a,b\in I$ and $a\le b$, then $[a,b]\subseteq I$.